# Can XML Sitemap include itself as one of the URLs?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

A little while ago I discovered an XML sitemap where the sitemap itself was included.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
  <!-- ... More uls ... -->
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml</loc> 
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Is this a mistake? Or was it done because they want it to be like that?
How does it affect SEO?
Does it let the crawler crawl to the sitemap again so all the pages are crawled more times?

Comment: "...because they want it...?" - that's not really a reason! ;) It's possible that it was an oversight... their CMS/Framework/plugin/script may have simply added it automatically?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah. I have seen this too. You are not alone.

I don't see any reason to do this. In fact it is redundant isn't it? And since sitemaps are designed to inform search engine about resources to be indexed and sitemaps are not indexed, it seems rather pointless. It was always a silly thing to do. You will see silly things all over the place especially in particular to the web and SEO so please take all of what you read with a serious dose of salt.

***You did the right thing by asking.***

Sitemaps have no effect on SEO in regard to site/page ranking and SERP placement. There is one performance metric that a sitemap can positively effect; whether a site is considered *crawlable* if there is a barrier that blocks the site from being crawled by the bot.

They are designed to inform search engines what resources that are available on any particular site. This is because there may be resources that are not linked, behind a login, or far too vast for timely discovery. End of story. If your site is smaller or medium sized, then search engines will likely prefer to just crawl your site. What they will do is read your sitemap, and compare it to their ability to crawl your site. If there is no difference and the site is small enough for natural discovery, then they will continue to crawl your site the old fashioned way. But still, from time to time they will compare your sitemap again to make sure that they are on track. If you suddenly expand your site, they may read from your sitemap. It is a good thing to do regardless, but not necessary for every site.

Comment: You said that sitemaps does not have any effect on SEO at all. I don't think so. From Google: "Search engine web crawlers like Googlebot read this file to more intelligently crawl your site.". SEO stands for Search Engine Optimization, so actually we are improving Google. We do this to make the search query relevant to the search results and so to your site. An option to do that is a sitemap i think. You could tell Google how important a page is in your site, how uptodate the page is and some information about the url. But i didn't really think it's a good thing to do. But can it be very bad?

Comment: @AndreasFurster Be careful reading into what Google says too much. Much of it is to benefit Google and a some of it is pure B.S. Sitemaps have absolutely ***NO EFFECT*** on search engine optimization. None. There are no metrics or database elements within the Google schema associated with sitemap data elements at all. Essentially, other than intelligently loading the fetch queue, the sitemap has no value. Often, it is completely ignored once compared to crawling a site the old fashioned way. Certainly, you cannot claim that search performance for any site increases by introducing a sitemap.

Comment: "Sitemaps have no effect on SEO what so ever" is a bit of an exaggeration.  See: [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)  Sitemaps can change Google from the standpoint of canonical URLs and content discovery.  Having them also gives you more info in webmaster tools.   Its true that they don't have much effect on rankings.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Which is precisely my point. Sitemaps have absolutely no effect on search performance for any given page, however, they do help in getting Google to index your site. Google, for some sites, really likes sitemaps and will index a site faster- up to the limit that Google feels your site can handle. But getting a page into the index is not optimizing. You cannot optimize what does not exist yet. There is no effect a sitemap can have on an already indexed page to make it perform better in search. But it does help sites get noticed and indexed granted.

Comment: I think 'sitemaps have no effect on search rankings' is a slightly clearer way of putting it, and I'd agree, but they're still worth having.

Comment: @TimFountain I agree. Perhaps my wording could have been better. I do not recommend sitemaps for smaller sites that can be easily crawled nor for sites that are not updated often. But then again, I do not argue against using one if someone wants to. Google will always take them as advice at least. For some sites they are critical.

Comment: @closetnoc why not edit your answer to clarify what you really mean then? i.e. "Sitemaps have no direct effect on search *rankings*, though they may assist google's crawler by speeding up the crawl process if present."

Comment: @Kev I will go one further than that. I found one metric that sitemaps can positively effect. I certainly did not mean to give anyone heartburn. I have been at this a long time and it did not occur to me that anyone would think of the term SEO as anything more that optimizing content for better search performance. I would never have considered sitemaps as part of SEO strategy as much as something you do when building a site. Thanks for your comment. Keep me honest! I appreciate it.

Comment: Appreciated. SEO isn't my bag, so everything I read I tend to take somewhat literally...so the whole sitemap thing....now I know :)

Comment: @Kev Most of the SEO stuff you will read is junk- *me too topic de' jure* conjecture. There are a few really good experts, but the truth of the matter is, most of them know what they know from only a few resources and some black-box style testing that Google tries very hard to suppress to avoid gaming the system. I happened to be fortunate to get a good inside glimpse of how Google really works about 2 years ago and I made a study over many years to know what is true and what is not. But still, I can get things wrong too. We all try and get it right, but the one who really knows is Google.